Nested conditions within WHERE clause
I have a table app_order with columns price (a number) and side (side can be either 'up' or 'down').
I need to write a postgreSQL condition within a WHERE clause that filters app_order entries for which price is both:

bigger than the average of 2 prices (max price with side='up' and min price with side='down') - 1 AND

smaller than the average of 2 prices (max price with side='up' and min price with side='down') + 1


How can I nest these conditions to achieve this?
At the end, I need a query similar to this:
SELECT
  market AS "MARKET",
  SUM(size*price) AS "SUM"
FROM
  app_order
WHERE
  --Missing condition here
GROUP BY
  market
ORDER BY
  market ASC


A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

With indexes:
create index idx1 on app_order(side,price);
create index idx2 on app_order(price)include(market,size);

The way you did it is pretty fast already, assuming you have indexes like the above set up.
You could shorten it and ask Postgres to not pop the top/bottom values from the index twice by explicitly materializing the CTE where you grab those, but apart from slightly shorter code, below isn't functionally different or perceivably faster from what you did already.
It's taking 1.5ms compared to your 3.7ms in this test on 900k random rows:
WITH cte("REF") AS MATERIALIZED(
  SELECT (SELECT MAX(price)FROM app_order WHERE side='up')
        +(SELECT MIN(price)FROM app_order WHERE side='down')/2)
SELECT market AS "MARKET"
      ,SUM(size * price) AS "SUM"
FROM app_order,cte
WHERE price > "REF" - 1
  AND price < "REF" + 1
GROUP BY market
ORDER BY market ASC;

The first index lets it grab the max right off the top of the BTree, min right from the bottom. The second makes it trivial to use those to find rows within the target price range and thanks to its include clause, all requested values are found in the index, removing the need to fetch market and size separately from the actual table.
As a result, this query is just three quick index-only scans, two of which take just a single step.

Without indexes
if you don't have them and don't want to have them, for some reason:

Calculate the common max+min/2 element once, give it a name.
Both max and min can be collected in a single scan of the table.
A FILTER clause can filter values entering each function independently, without the need for separate queries to have different WHERE conditions.
You can attach the calculated value using cross join, any join..on true or just a comma ,.
Re-use the pre-calculated value in your main query.

If it wasn't for the typos, formatting and emulation of the filter clause with a case, that's pretty much what @Littlefoot already suggested. It's not just shorter and simpler, it's way faster: on 500k rows you'll find your approach takes 986ms and this goes down to 424ms, giving you the same result.
Demo at db<>fiddle:
SELECT market AS "MARKET"
      ,SUM(size * price) AS "SUM"
FROM app_order 
CROSS JOIN(SELECT ( MAX(price)FILTER(WHERE side='up')
                   +MIN(price)FILTER(WHERE side='down'))/2 as "MID"
           FROM app_order)as subq
WHERE price > "MID" - 1
  AND price < "MID" + 1
GROUP BY market
ORDER BY market ASC;


Amazing, thanks a lot for the great explanation on the loading times. Awesome work!

This is how I understood the question.
Using a CTE (or a subquery; pick the one you prefer), find max "up" and min "down" price. Then join the original app_order table with a CTE on conditions you specified.
Something like this:
WITH
   minimax
   AS
      (SELECT MAX (CASE WHEN side = 'up' THEN price ELSE NULL END) max_up_price,
              MIN (CASE WHEN side = 'down' THEN price ELSE NULL END) min_down_price
         FROM app_order)
  SELECT o.market, SUM (o.size * o.price) sum_size_price
    FROM app_order o
         JOIN minimaya
            ON     o.price > (a.max_up_price + a.min_down_price) / 2 - 1
               AND o.price < (a.max_up_price + a.min_down_price) / 2 + 1
GROUP BY o.market            ---------------------------------------                 
                             this is the "average of two prices" 
                             you mentioned


Smart solution. Thanks for this! I ended up using the solution on my answer. Again, thanks for this great workaround.

If the above answered your question then please accept it.
This helps future users with the same or very similar questions.
Also it removes the question from the unanswered queue.
Please do not leave successfully answered questions s unanswered.

Ended up finding the solution (thanks anyway!):
SELECT
  market AS "MARKET",
  SUM(size * price) AS "SUM"
FROM
  app_order
WHERE
  price > (
    (SELECT MAX(price) FROM app_order WHERE side = 'up') + 
    (SELECT MIN(price) FROM app_order WHERE side = 'down')
  ) / 2 - 1
  AND
  price < (
    (SELECT MAX(price) FROM app_order WHERE side = 'up') + 
    (SELECT MIN(price) FROM app_order WHERE side = 'down')
  ) / 2 + 1
GROUP BY
  market
ORDER BY
  market ASC;

